# Terraform- Azure Event Grid Subscription with Event hub endpoint

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Doing [Event Grid Subscription with a EventHub endpoint](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription)

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription" "example" {
  name                = "example-event-subscription"
  system_topic        = azurerm_system_topic.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  eventhub_endpoint {
    eventhub_endpoint_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
  }
```

I got the error like

`Blocks of type "eventhub_endpoint" are not expected here.`

Not sure what I'm missing here. Is the `eventhub_endpoint` is not a valid one  ? How can i configure the eventhub for my event grid sub ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please update your script as

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription" "example" {
  name                = "example-event-subscription"
  system_topic        = azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  eventhub_endpoint_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription#eventhub_endpoint_id).
[image]

For example (I use terraform 0.15.4 on windows)

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {

   
        subscription_id = "e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68"
        client_id = "42e0d080-b1f3-40cf-8db6-c4c522d988c4"
        client_secret = "Gbx2eK64iqq_g_3NCA.ClJDfQpIjoae:"
        tenant_id = "e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb"
        features {}

}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "testhubname0123"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  capacity            = 1

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub" "example" {
  name                = "testhub0123"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  partition_count     = 2
  message_retention   = 1
}
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic" "example" {
  name                   = "example-system-topic"
  location               = "Global"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  source_arm_resource_id = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  topic_type             = "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups"
}

resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription" "example" {
  name                = "example-event-subscription"
  system_topic        = azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  eventhub_endpoint_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
}
```

[image]